# How to evaluate variable inside the css pseudo class in SASS

Tags: css, sass

I'm new to SASS. I want to get the css which evaluate the value inside the CSS class using for loop SASS. In my case, i want to get ul:nth-child(**1**) .e-classA instead of ul:nth-child(**2**) .e-classA. I'm getting error when used &ul:nth-child(#{$i} - 1)

```
$text-indent: 12px;
$width: 14px;

@for $i from 2 through 4 {
    &ul:nth-child(#{$i} - 1) {

      & .e-classA {
        text-indent: $text-indent * #{$i};

        &.e-classB {
          text-indent: ($text-indent * #{$i}) + $width;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Actual output:

```
Error: Invalid CSS after "...m 2 through 4 {": expected "}", was "nth-child(#{$i}..."
        on line 4 of stdin
>> @for $i from 2 through 4 {
   --------------------------^
```

Expected output:

```
ul:nth-child(1) .e-classA {
    text-indent: 24px;
}

ul:nth-child(1) .e-classA.e-classB {
    text-indent: 38px;
}

ul:nth-child(2) .e-classA {
    text-indent: 36px;
}

ul:nth-child(2) .e-classA.e-classB {
    text-indent: 50px;
}

ul:nth-child(3) .e-classA {
    text-indent: 48px;
}

ul:nth-child(3) .e-classA.e-classB {
    text-indent: 62px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want SASS to do some math, move the calculation inside `#{...}`. Second problem might be the `&` at the beginning of `&ul:...`, you don't need it there to get the result.

I fixed you code:

```
$text-indent: 12px;
$width: 14px;

@for $i from 2 through 4 {
    ul:nth-child(#{$i - 1}) {

      & .e-classA {
        text-indent:  #{$text-indent * $i};

        &.e-classB {
          text-indent: #{($text-indent * $i) + $width};
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And tested in sassmeister and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved myself by the below modification.

***&ul:nth-child(#{$i - 1}) ***